# ANDROID Time picker how to display two numbers in hour and minute

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timepicker, android-timepicker

Hi everyone i would like to display when i click a button, two number in hour and minute.

my code is:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int hour= timePicker.getCurrentHour();
        int minute=timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"CLOCK--> "+ String.valueOf(hour)+":"+String.valueOf(minute),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

But the output is for example "9:8".

I want display "09:08".

Sorry for my english =)

Comment: Use a Formatter or do it by hand (h<10 ? "0"+h : String.valueOf(h))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"CLOCK--> "+ String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minute),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use like this:

```
String time = "";
    time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a zero at the left if number is lower than 10

```
String hrstr = hour < 10 ? //If hour is lower than 10, add a zero on the left 
    '0' + hour : hour;
String minstr = min < 10 ? //If minute is lower than 10, add a zero on the left
    '0' + min : min;
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"CLOCK--> "+ hrstr +":"+minstr,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(mContext, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
        yourView.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", selectedHour, selectedMinute));
    }
}, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
mTimePicker.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Material Time Picker using Kotlin. Please make sure to Material Designing Library add in your build.Gradle Module File. Try This!!, It's Working....

```
val mTimePicker : MaterialTimePicker

    // Check System Format
    val isSystem24Hour = is24HourFormat(this)
    // timePicker Format according to System Format
    val clockFormat = if (isSystem24Hour) TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H else TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H

    // build the MaterialTimePicker Dialog
    mTimePicker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
        .setTimeFormat(clockFormat)
        .setHour(12)
        .setMinute(0)
        .setTitleText("Set Time")
        .build()

    // Show the MaterialTimePicker
    mTimePicker.show(supportFragmentManager,"Boss")

    // Action by Positive response "OK"
    mTimePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
        val hour = mTimePicker.hour
        val minute = mTimePicker.minute
        etMTimePicker.setText(String.format("%02d : %02d",hour,minute))
    }
```